# Setting UIPrerenderedIcon from a configuration file in Xcode

Tags: ios, info-plist

It seems I am not able to set `UIPrerenderedIcon` in my `Info.plist`, because [it is ignored as of iPhone OS 2.1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1614/_index.html). You can't provide a `String` value of `YES`, this is no longer supported.

Is there any other way to do this without necessarly creating a separate Info.plist (e.g., using a pre–build run script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. You will have to add a "Run Script" build phase, before "Compile Sources":

> #!/usr/bin/env sh
>
> set -o errexit set -o nounset
>
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set UIPrerenderedIcon ${YOUR_CONFIG_KEY}"
>   "${PROJECT_DIR}/*-Info.plist"

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to set value dynamically using command from shell script or terminal, you can do that as below:

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIPrerenderedIcon YES" YOUR_PLIST_FILE_PATH

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIcons:CFBundlePrimaryIcon:UIPrerenderedIcon YES" YOUR_PLIST_FILE_PATH
```